# How can I delete a dictionary object using python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've got a dictionary that I am trying to remove a specific object.

```
{
  "authorizationQualifier": "00",
  "testIndicator": " ",
  "functionalGroups": [
    {
      "functionalIdentifierCode": "SC",
      "applicationSenderCode": "6088385400",
      "applicationReceiverCode": "3147392555",
      "transactions": [
        {
          "name": null,
          "transactionSetIdentifierCode": "832",
          "transactionSetControlNumber": "000000001",
          "implementationConventionReference": null,
          "segments": [
            {
              "BCT": {
                "BCT01": "PS",
                "BCT03": "2",
                "id": "BCT"
                     }
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to delete the "segments" list of objects while keeping the functional groups and transactions lists.

I've tried,

```
ediconverted = open("converted.json", "w")
with open('832.json','r') as jsonfile:
    json_content = json.load(jsonfile)

for element in json_content:
    element.pop('segments', None)

with open('converted.json', 'w') as data_file:
    json_content = json.dump(json_content, data_file)
```

Comment: Please post the way you tried it.

Comment: That's not a dictionary; it's a block of JSON.

Comment: I used loads() to deserialize the json file to a dictionary. Then I can get each list key by using - shortdata = data["functionalGroups"][0]["transactions"][0] (data being the deserialized json file); however I am unclear on how to remove the segments list. Ive tried .pop with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific structure, let's name it d, the following will work:

```
del d["functionalGroups"][0]["transactions"][0]["segments"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove it for all the groups and transactions:

```
for g in data["functionalGroups"]: 
    for d in g["transactions"]: 
        d.pop("segments")
        # or, if segments is an optional key
        d.pop("segments", None)
```

You could do [`del d["segments"]`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) which has a little less overhead as it does not return anything, but it doesn't offer the option to smoothly handle the case where `"segments"` is not present (as does [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)).

Comment: This one did it as well, thank you!